# 'This is the 'bait'. You probably need to add one of the SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_* nuget packages

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core 2 in my application using SQLite as my database provider.

I have added references to the following in my project:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core
- Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
- SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green
- SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2
- SQLitePCLRaw.core
- SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3

I am trying to use the `IMigrator` on my dbcontext to setup my initial database like so:

```
using (var dbContext = new DbContext())
{
    var migrator = dbContext.GetInfrastructure().GetRequiredService<IMigrator>();
    migrator.Migrate();
}
```

In my `DbContext` I am setting adding the service with:

```
options.UseSqlite(connectionString);
```

My connection string is just a local path.

This all seems like what I should be doing as per Microsoft's documentation. However when I try to run my application, I get the following error:

> 'This is the 'bait'.  You probably need to add one of the
>   SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_* nuget packages to your platform project.'

As far as I'm aware I have added a `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_*` package since I am referencing both `SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green` and `SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2`.

Does anyone know of a way to fix this error and use SQLite as my database provider?

**Edit**

My Data project .csproj (slightly redacted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{EA5DB634-7838-4C96-8DF5-4051B31DFFD2}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Data</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Data</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>..\Build\Debug\bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>..\Build\Release\bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>..\Build\Debug\bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <OutputPath>..\Build\Release\bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite">
      <HintPath>..\References\Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core.2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore">
      <HintPath>..\References\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational">
      <HintPath>..\References\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core">
      <HintPath>..\References\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core.2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer">
      <HintPath>..\References\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a84b7dcfb1391f7f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\References\SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green.1.1.7\lib\net45\SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8226ea5df37bcae9, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\References\SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green.1.1.7\lib\net45\SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1488e028ca7ab535, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\References\SQLitePCLRaw.core.1.1.7\lib\net45\SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9c301db686d0bd12, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\References\SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.net45.1.1.7\lib\net45\SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\References\System.Collections.Immutable.1.4.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Collections.Immutable.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations">
      <HintPath>..\References\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.4.4.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.104.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\References\System.Data.SQLite.1.0.104.0\System.Data.SQLite.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Interactive.Async, Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\References\System.Interactive.Async.3.1.1\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Interactive.Async.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Sqlite\SqliteDbConnectionFactory.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

My DbContext is in a different project that references my Data project. The `SqliteDbConnectionFactory` sets up the `UseSqlite` on the `DbContextOptionsBuilder` from an `OnConfiguring` override in my DbContext.

Comment: Could you share your `*.csproj` file?

Comment: @bricelam I've added my csproj and some more detail in an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with judicious use of a decompiler, it turns out the NetStandard1.1 built `SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll` assembly has the bait exception baked into it at compile time, while the net45 version correctly calls the SQLite provider initialiser.

I had been using the NetStandard assemblies at first since all the new Entity Framework and AspNetcore assemblies use some flavour of NetStandard so when I changed to net45 to test different configurations I neglected to delete by bin folder and so was getting conflicts with the different versions.

Clearing out the bin folder and only referencing net45 versions of the SQLitePCLRaw assemblies allowed the provider to be initialised.

The next error I ran into was that `e_sqlite.dll` could not be found. This is an un-managed assembly found in one of the `SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.*` NuGet packages. I downloaded the `SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.v110_xp` package and added `e_sqlite.dll` as a resource into my project which is copied into my bin directory at runtime.

Once I had the `e_sqlite.dll` in my bin, my project started successfully and created my database.

Comment: because ... you know ...nothing is ever as simple as installing a nuget package ... :)

Comment: @Noctis not when it comes to Dot Net Core 2 apparently.

Comment: hehe ...been playing with it myself a bit lately. but it's true to any new tech out there. there were similar issues with 1.0 and 1.1 where different versions would pull different dependencies, and some where incompatible, and you would spend hours cursing at digital gods because your application worked a second ago and now it wouldn't compile ... At least you've paved the way for the next unsuspecting soul and he might find your SO post and be a little bit happier.